# How to make `truncate-lines` nil and `auto-fill-mode` off in magit buffers

Tags: magit

I got

```
(setq-default fill-column 80)
(setq-default truncate-lines nil) ;; which is default
```

When using magit in Emacs, I know that I should avoid long commit messages, but sometimes they just cannot be avoid.

The problem is: `(setq-default truncate-lines nil)` which is default setting does not work in **magit: project** buffer(there is a straight right arrow at the end of line), the `(setq-default fill-column 80)` does not work in **COMMIT_EDITMSG** buffer, and the `fill-column` value in it is 72 not 80.

But what I really want is: make the `truncate-lines` to `nil` in **magit: project** buffer as well so I can see long lines in one window but not break it into several different lines, **AND** turn on auto-fill-mode in **COMMIT_EDITMSG** buffer, so long commit messages won't be broken into several different lines while I'm typing.

NOTE: DO NOT affect other buffers like **magit-log** buffer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can add setting specific to `magit-status` to `magit-status-mode-hook`:

   ```
   (add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook
             (lambda () 
                (setq truncate-lines nil)))
   ```
2. Starting with Magit `v2.1.0`, `COMMIT_EDITMSG` files are edited using`text-mode` with the *minor* mode `git-commit-mode` also turned on. You need to add your configuration to `git-commit-mode-hook`:

   ```
   (add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for `git-commit-mode-hook`, and `magit-mode-hook` does not work for **COMMIT_EDITMSG** buffer, so I delete your **NOTE**.